# Chrome not serving pages with service-worker using workbox

Tags: service-worker, offline, workbox, stenciljs

Im working on a offline first app built with stencil in combination with capacitorjs. Im having trouble testing the service worker functionality in chrome. When i emulate the offline mode chrome gives a console warning :

[image: chrome error]

In firefox everything is working as expected when using offline mode. I cannot figure out what is going wrong. Here is the service worker code:

```
// change to the version you get from `npm ls workbox-build`
importScripts('workbox-v4.3.1/workbox-sw.js');

workbox.setConfig({
  debug: true,
});

// your custom service worker code
self.addEventListener("message", ({ data }) => {
    if (data === "skipWaiting") {
      self.skipWaiting();
    }
  });

self.addEventListener('push', event => {
  console.log(`Push received with data "${event.data.text()}"`);

  const title = 'Push Notification';
  const options = {
    body: `${event.data.text()}`,
    data: { href: 'www.simbuka.com' },
    actions: [
      { action: 'details', title: 'Details' },
      { action: 'dismiss', title: 'Dismiss' },
    ],
  };

  event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', event => {
  const notification = event.notification;
  const action = event.action;

  if (action === 'dismiss') {
    notification.close();
  } else {
    // This handles both notification click and 'details' action,
    // because some platforms might not support actions.
    clients.openWindow(notification.data.href);
    notification.close();
  }
});


self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  clients.claim();
});



// the precache manifest will be injected into the following line
try {
  workbox.precaching.cleanupOutdatedCaches();
  workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([]);
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}


// // Solution 1: default page handler for offline usage,
// // where the browser does not how to handle deep links
// // it's a SinglePageAplication, so each path that is a navigation should default to index.html
// self.workbox.routing.registerRoute(
//   ({ event }) => event.request.mode === 'navigate',
//   async (event) => {
//     const defaultBase = '/index.html';
//     return caches
//       .match(workbox.precaching.getCacheKeyForURL(defaultBase))
//       .then(response => {
//           console.log('default nav handler request',event.request)
//           console.log('default nav handler response',response)
//           return response || fetch(defaultBase);
//       })
//       .catch(err => {
//         return fetch(defaultBase);
//       });
//   }
// );

// Solution 2: This "catch" handler is triggered when any of the other routes fail to
// generate a response.
// self.workbox.routing.setCatchHandler(({event}) => {
//   console.log('in catch handler workbox')
//   // The FALLBACK_URL entries must be added to the cache ahead of time, either
//   // via runtime or precaching. If they are precached, then call
//   // `matchPrecache(FALLBACK_URL)` (from the `workbox-precaching` package)
//   // to get the response from the correct cache.
//   //
//   // Use event, request, and url to figure out how to respond.
//   // One approach would be to use request.destination, see
//   // https://medium.com/dev-channel/service-worker-caching-strategies-based-on-request-types-57411dd7652c
//   switch (event.request.destination) {
//     case 'document':
//       // If using precached URLs:
//       // return matchPrecache(FALLBACK_HTML_URL);
//       return caches.match('/index.html');
//     break;

//     // case 'image':
//     //   // If using precached URLs:
//     //   // return matchPrecache(FALLBACK_IMAGE_URL);
//     //   return caches.match(FALLBACK_IMAGE_URL);
//     // break;

//     // case 'font':
//     //   // If using precached URLs:
//     //   // return matchPrecache(FALLBACK_FONT_URL);
//     //   return caches.match(FALLBACK_FONT_URL);
//     // break;

//     default:
//       // If we don't have a fallback, just return an error response.
//       return Response.error();
//   }
// });
```

I tried several thing. I rebuilt the code without esm leaving only app.js with polyfills but that gives the same message. I tried adding a default page handler in the service worker (see commented code in service worker: solution 1. I tried adding catch handler for uncached requests (see solution 2 in commented code from service worker). But nothing works, and firefox seems to work just fine without any of the default handler.

I verified the service worker running, and up to date. I verified that workbox is caching resources and responding to them, but somehow it is not working in chrome (88) and firefox (86) does give response. The service worker is in the correct scope (in the root of www folder). Does anybody have an idea what im doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't know what would cause different behavior in Firefox and Chrome. Can you share a URL at which this could be reproduced? Either publicly, or DM `@jeffposnick` on Twitter. Thanks!

Comment: no its not yet hosted, only local dev server. I can provide additional information if you like?

Comment: If you could possibly put it somewhere public, like on glitch.com or elsewhere, that would help in debugging. Also, have you tried loading it in a Chrome Incognito window and see if reproduces there?